# Reorder sheets of an existing excel file in S3 - Python Lambda

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, openpyxl

I am generating an excel file with multiple sheets in the below order:

```
["COMP1_hires","COMP2_hires","COMP1_det","COMP2_det"]
```

I want to re-order the sheets in the below order:

```
["COMP1_hires","COMP1_det","COMP2_hires","COMP2_det"]
```

My file is generated in a specific folder in S3. Is there a way to change the sheet order during or after the excel file generation?

Below is my current working code. This code generates an excel file with separate sheet for each component:

```
    filename = 'exported_comp_file_'+today
    with io.BytesIO() as output:
            with pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
                for comp in components_sep:
                    df1= df[df['component']==comp]
                    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=comp, index=False)
                writer.save()
                data = output.getvalue()
                
                s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
                s3.Bucket('demo bucket').put_object(Key='myfolder/'+filename+'.xlsx', Body=data)
```

comp in the above code is ["COMP1_hires","COMP2_hires","COMP1_det","COMP2_det"]. So an excel file with sheet for every component above is generated. How to reorder the sheets in the file?

Comment: I think you can reorder the `components_sep` in advance?

Comment: Not sure where :( Can you pls guide?

Comment: Just replace the line where you are defining `components_sep` list with the list of your desired order. `components_sep = ["COMP1_hires","COMP1_det","COMP2_hires","COMP2_det"]`